# Screen intensity before and after inactivity

Tags: laptop, screen

On my ThinkPad W520 laptop, after a short period of inactivity (eg. no mouse movement) on battery, the screen dims for power saving. When I move the mouse (ie. , the screen lights back up, but not at the same level (darker) than it was before.

I've seen some code a while ago with X managing the dimness (?) but can't remember where it was. Maybe I can configure something in X or somehow do something with it?

**Who is responsible for lighting the screen up when the mouse moves?** 
How do I make it go back to its original setting when it becomes active again?

Comment: The question wasn't about turning off inactivity dimming, but how to gain back the same light intensity after moving the mouse, coming back from inactivity.

Answer (score 5):

#### For 11.04 and earlier:

This is done (screen dimming) as a part of power savings while on battery power.

You can change this in "Power Management" in System settings.

Unselect "Dim display when idle" on the On Battery Power tab.

[image: Dim display]

For additional information see

- https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/power-batterylife.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/power-brighter.html

Answer (score 2):

#### For 11.10 and newer:

It is a settings in `System Settings` > `Brightness and Lock`

Open `System Settings` and goto `Brightness and Lock` icon

[image: Where to find Brightness and Lock]

Yours might be looking like

[image: One minute screen lock]

Change the `Turn screen off when inactive for:` to `Never`

[image: Never screen lock]