# Screen darkens after 40 seconds of inactivity

Tags: 10.04, screen, monitor, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off the screen dimming after inactivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57998/how-do-i-turn-off-the-screen-dimming-after-inactivity)

I am running Linux Ubuntu 10.04 on my Dell laptop. There's a setting that I would like to change, but I don't know how.

After about 40 seconds of inactivity, my screen gets darker. Then when I click again on my mouse or keyboard, it comes back bright again.
I would like to disable this setting.